# vs code snippets sometimes not loading

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Basically sometimes when I open vs code it does not show me snippets like it normally does so I manually used ctrl + space and it just said loading anyone else have gotten the same problem or knows the solution

This happens with all languages.

Comment: any particular programming languages you are writing in / where this is happening in?

Comment: @starball It happens with all languages but I'm a learning jsx and tawind currently.

Comment: is it just snippets? or is it also other things in the suggestions widget?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't choice snippets working properly in new files in VS Code 1.80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668211/why-arent-choice-snippets-working-properly-in-new-files-in-vs-code-1-80)

Comment: @starball ty for trying but I don't think that answers it it might be my weak cpu

Comment: which snippets are not working? can you [edit] to give some examples? If they are from extensions, please also specify which extension they are from.

Comment: does the problem still happen in VS Code 1.80.1? What is an "umm"? You still didn't provide any examples.

Comment: umm that was a typo I wanted to say good news let me check my vscode version I am already in the 1.80.1